# Update results in a column from multiple columns with different names

Tags: stata

[image]

Based on the image, I would like to loop through the columns to find where there is a text `mo`. It updates `mo` with the results not the text `mo`. The challenge has been how to select the result in the next column different from where `mo` is.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that, in your example, you want replace "mo" in rows 1-3 of var1 with 3, 4, and 5? For var1 to have "mo" then presumably it is a string variable, and you will be trying to store a numeric value as a string. This is not a big problem, but it is difficult to see the value of what you are trying to do. This makes me think you perhaps are taking a long route to a destination more easily reached by a different path. Can you tell us more about your eventual goal for this data? What role does "mo" play in var1 that cannot be solved by using var2 directly?

Comment: The task is, I want to aggregate all the mo into one column, where I have all the results for the tests in that column mo. e.g have a column mo,  where all the results of mo are updated. This is a sample of the dataset where there are many other tests that have their data in this way. So I would need to loop through to find the test like here mo, pick the result to update a mo result column instead of the var2,4,6,8. The goal is collate all the test results into a single column.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to my comment above suggests to me that the question you ask reflects the wrong approach to the larger problem. Your description suggests that you have observations with a varying number of testname/testvalue pairs, such as

```
  +----------------------------------------+
  | id   day   test1   val1   test2   val2 |
  |----------------------------------------|
  |  A     1      mo     11              . |
  |  A     2      mo     12      df   98.2 |
  |----------------------------------------|
  |  B     1      df   98.3      mo     23 |
  |  B     2      mo     14              . |
  +----------------------------------------+
```

and your objective is to produce observations that look like this

```
  +----------------------+
  | id   day     df   mo |
  |----------------------|
  |  A     1      .   11 |
  |  A     2   98.2   12 |
  |----------------------|
  |  B     1   98.3   23 |
  |  B     2      .   14 |
  +----------------------+
```

If that is the case, here is a reproducible example that you can copy, paste into Stata's Do-file Editor window, execute it, and examine the output to see how the technique avoids all the complexity you introduce by trying to use loops to accomplish the task. The `reshape` command is one of Stata's most powerful data management tools and it will benefit you to learn how to use it.

```
clear
input str8 id int day str8 test1 float val1 str8 test2 float val2
A 1 "mo" 11 "" .
A 2 "mo" 12 "df" 98.2
B 1 "df" 98.3 "mo" 23
B 2 "mo" 14 "" .
end
list, sepby(id) noobs
reshape long test val, i(id day) j(num)
drop if missing(test)
drop num
list, sepby(id) noobs
reshape wide val, i(id day) j(test) str
rename val* *
list, sepby(id) noobs
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the perspective and solution. It has worked.